# Symfony2 - Loading JS files with assetic from inside a custom form field type widget

Tags: symfony, twig, assetic

So I need a custom form field type and in the block that defines the field code I need to load some JS with assetic.

```
{% block my_form_field_type_widget %}
    {% spaceless %}
        <input type="hidden" name="{{ full_name }}" id="{{ id }}" autocomplete='off'/>
        {% javascripts
            '@MyModuleBundle/Resources/public/js/fileToLoad.js'
            filter="?yui_js"
        %}
            <script src="{{ asset_url }}"></script>
        {% endjavascripts %}

        <script type="text/javascript">
           useFunctionInFileToLoadJS();
        </script>
    {% endspaceless %}
{% endblock %}
```

The problem I'm having is that the path to the resource that is generated by Assetic is wrong and results in a 404:

```
<script src="/_controller/js/6f0730f.js">
```

it should be something like:

```
<script src="/app_dev.php/js/6f0730f.js">
```

Is there a way arround this?

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried to specify explicitely the output path/file?

```
{% block javascripts %}
    {% javascripts
        '@MyModuleBundle/Resources/public/js/fileToLoad.js'
        filter="?yui_js"
        output='build/fileToLoad.js'
    %}
    <script src="{{ asset_url | replace({'/app_dev.php': ''}) }}"></script>
{% endjavascripts %}
```

Comment: We are going to follow a different route and have a service that takes care of the JS loading. Still haven't finalized how it will work. :)

Comment: You mean, with require-like lib for async js loading? I'd be interested if you manage to do that + Assetic ;)